# How to get GHCi running correctly within ansi-term window in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, ghci, ansi-term

For some reason, I'm loosing the up-arrow and DEL keys after launching GHCi from within an *ansi-term* window in Emacs.
(These keys work as expected from within the *ansi-term* window, before launching GHCi.)
And RET doesn't produce a line feed, just a carriage return.
I don't observe any of these oddities when launching GHCi from my normal *Terminal* application under MacOS X.

Using Emac's *view-lossage* feature I find:

```
 <menu-bar> <Terminal> <Character mode> [term-char-mode]
 <up> [term-send-up]
 <return> [term-send-raw]
 <backspace> [term-send-backspace]
 <menu-bar> <Terminal> <Line mode> [term-line-mode]
 <up> [previous-line]
 <return> [term-send-input]
 <backspace> [delete-backward-char]
 C-h l [view-lossage]
```

(Note: The above was taken *after* launching GHCi from within the *ansi-term* window of Emacs.)

And it looks like I may want to switch to *Line* mode while running GHCi.
(I normally run the *ansi-term* window in *Character* mode, because it gives me an experience more similar to working in the *Terminal* application.)

It looks like `M-p` will recover past commands.
So, if I can figure out how to get the up-arrow remapped to `M-p` while in GHCi, then I should be pretty close to my usual *GHCi-in-Terminal* experience.

However, there's one remaining problem: I'm still not getting a line feed when hitting RET.
And this is really screwing things up, both asthetically and functionally.

It's strange, because the RET key typed at either the *ansi-term* prompt, or the GHCi (launched from within *ansi-term*) prompt (with the *ansi-term* window set to *Line* mode) both send the same command: `term-send-input`.
And the *ansi-term* does the right thing in response to this command.
So, why doesn't GHCi do the right thing?

Perhaps, I need to remap RET to: `CR/LF; term-send-input` while in GHCi?
Is this even possible (i.e. - doing application-specific key remapping withing the *ansi-term* window)?